# Ubuntu Cinnamon menu is too tall for my netbooks screen

Tags: resolution, menu, cinnamon

I decided I wanted to try out ubuntu cinnamon on my acer aspire one d257, but the start menu is too tall for the 1024x600 display. Please help me, I do not need cinnamon to work but it would be a nice alternative to unity. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative please install this applet (Configurable Menu):
http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/171

Read the information and possibilities. One possible option on this applet is allow to resize the menu with the mouse to any size that you want.

I'm the author, so any problem or request you can directly speak with me.
https://github.com/lestcape/Configurable-Menu

Good day.